# How to Send a segue in didSelectItemAt

Tags: iphone, swift, core-data, uicollectionview, segue

I am trying to make a segue that sends a string to a variable in the next view controller. This string is the text inside a label that is inside a collection view cell, the text inside the label is from CoreData. When the user presses the cell, it is meant to segue to the next view controller and have the text of the cell previously selected in a variable. I am not sure how to do this, this is my didSelect function which is able to get the text of the selected cell:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cellP", for: indexPath) as! CCCollectionViewCell
    let project = projectList[indexPath.row]

    if project.name! == "Hi " {
            print("Yes")
    }
    else {
            print("no")
    }

    print(project.name!)

}
```

The problem is I am not sure how to send this value (project.name!) of the selected cell in a segue to the next view controller variable.

Comment: Is your segue perform when you select cell means are you able to move to nextViewController?

Comment: **Never** call `dequeueReusableCell` outside of `cellForItemAtIndexPath`. Get the data from the data source array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this way.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let vc = segue.destination as! NextViewController //Your ViewController class
    if let cell = sender as? UICollectionViewCell,
       let indexPath = self.collectionView.indexPath(for: cell){

         let project = projectList[indexPath.row]
         print(project.name)
         vc.name = project.name
    }
}
```

Now simply in your `NextViewController` create one property of type `String`.

```
var name = String()
```